# updating table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a table that will initialize, but will not update. I use a few inputs, which then get called by a function to calculate the outputs. They will initialize with the correct values, but when I click the actionButton, nothing happens.

```
output$view<-renderTable({
    tabSvol<-isolate(
               data.frame(
                 S=c(
                    func1(input$in1),
                    func2(input$in2),
                    func3(input$in1,input$2)
                 )
               )
             )
    tabSvol
  })
```

Comment: `output$view` Appears to have no dependency on any action button. That’s why no update occurs when you click. In fact, `view`’s dependencies on all the reactives referenced are suppressed by `isolate`. It’s bad practice to conflate data wrangling and presentation. We need a minimum reproducible example, not just a code fragment.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want me to add. This code isn't going to run unless I copy paste my entire project. for now I've added



```newval1<-eventReactive(input$update, {func1(input$in1)})```
for each of the three functions, and replaced func1 in output$view with newval1(). It appears to be working as far as I can tell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MRE that allows you to add rows to a reactive table.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("a", "A: ", value=NA),
    selectInput("b", "B:", choices=c("X", "Y", "Z")),
    actionButton("add", "Add row"),
    tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(table=tibble(A=numeric(0), B=character(0)))
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        rv$table
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        rv$table <- rv$table %>% add_row(A=input$a, B=input$b)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```